# String in for loop doesn't get full context

Tags: java, string, for-loop, jsoup

Since I'm a beginner I have no clue about the following problem, I've did hours of research but nothing could help me.
I have declared a static string which will be assigned in a for loop, later the string get's printed out in the console but it doesn't contain the full context.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class dothework {

    static String info;

    public void scrapeinfo() throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("html").get();

        Elements el_name = doc.select(".champ-name");
        Elements el_speed = doc.select(".speed");
        Elements el_altitude = doc.select(".altitude");

        el_name.size();
        el_speed.size();
        el_altitude.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String name = el_name.get(i).text();
            String speed = el_speed.get(i).text();
            String altitude = el_altitude.get(i).text();
            String tempinfo = (name+": "+speed+" ("+altitude+")");
            System.out.println(tempinfo);
            info = tempinfo;
        }
    }

    public void printinfo() {
        System.out.println(info);
    }
}
```

While `System.out.println(tempinfo);` prints out the full information of 5 rows each containing name, speed and altitude the other `System.out.println(info);` prints out just one row with name, speed and altitude. So the problem is that the strings differ even though I equalized them here:`info = tempinfo;`. I guess that has something to do with the for-loop and/or with the modifier but I can't figure it out. Please help me.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between `info = tempinfo;` and `info += tempinfo;`?

Comment: You're missing a main method to say this is a [mcve], but remove the static on the string

Comment: I think OP just wants to have all 5 lines that get printed in the loop to the String `info` and also have it print in 5 lines... as in add each `tempinfo` followed by a newline to `info`... `info += tempinfo + "\n"`

Comment: Yeah, he's throwing out the previous information each time he sets info to refer to a new tempinfo String. He wants to do `info += tempinfo + "\n";` or some such. Not a very clear question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm asking why the output of those two strings differ? And how is it possible that the output of info really equals the output of tempinfo? I'm sorry that I didn't really asked this...

Comment: @JohnDhoe: it's only doing what you tell it to do. When you call `info = tempinfo;` you're throwing away any String that into was previously holding. At the end of your loop, info only holds the value from the *last* tempinfo.

Comment: @JohnDhoe `info` is getting replaced by `tempinfo` on each loop iteration which leaves you with only the last `tempinfo` in `info` when you call `printinfo`.

Comment: `info += tempinfo + "\n";` - this did the math. I'm really thankful!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `StringBuilder` to accumulate the lines.

```
public class Dothework {

    StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();

    // for... 

        info.append(tempinfo).append("\n");
```

Currently, each iteration of the loop overwrites the previous value stored in the string.  You also don't need a static variable here.

Comment: My bad on closing it. But OP has no arraylist, so that's a poor dupe